# Issues with using youtube auto generated transcript with Jwplayer

Tags: html, youtube, html5-video, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am facing issues with using youtube auto generated transcript with Jwplayer.

Here are links

http://academy.social27.com/welcome.aspx --- This is for Jwplayer

Youtube video link is
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GSGhlo5R-I

Transcript vtt file link is: http://s27platformmedia.blob.core.windows.net/l27lms/sandbox/3551/eba11ed0-fd2d-48ee-8b7d-b813a928cb18.vtt

So in Youtube video the transcript is sliding up as the lines are spoken by instructor in video. So there is sliding effect.

But in case of Jwplayer its not happening like that and it looks that the already spoken lines are coming together.

How could it can be fixed with Jwplayer and how it can work like youtube.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a number of errors in your Web VTT file when I check it here:
https://quuz.org/webvtt/

Comment: vtt is generated by youtube. if it should have errors then jwplayer will not load it. But its loading for my video in player it means its valid.